# Odd Synergy Configuration Assistance

Tags: synergy

Looking to get some help on setting up synergy with a rather odd configuration (or at least odd to configure in synergy). My setup is shown below:

```
                            -------------------------
                            |      Server Screen1   |
                            |                       |
                            |                       |
                            |                       |
                            -------------------------
              ------------------------------------------------------
              | Client1 Screen1|| Server Screen2 ||Client2 Screen1 |
              |                ||                ||                |
              |                ||                ||                |
              |                ||                ||                |
              ------------------------------------------------------
```

Even if I could only reach server screen #1 from server screen #2 and not from the small overlapping sections with the two client machines, I would be happy.
Any advice on the matter would be rather appreciated.

Comment: What OSes? Which version of synergy? (Free, plus or pro?)

Comment: Server is windows 7 enterprise x64, client 1 is windows 10 x32, and client 2 is unfortunately windows vista x64. Synergy is the latest version of plus.

Comment: I have a very similar configuration. It is quite odd and I can't seem to make it work either. Also on Synergy Pro/Plus, whatever is the paid latest.
I'm on Mac and Windows, but between those two shouldn't make much diff in the config. My server is on Windows, so should still be applicable, I think.

Comment: I will add that weirdly it works just fine when my server is the Mac, but this is not the configuration I need. :/